# Hide UITabbar and show Toolbar on show segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, uitabbar

on my xcode project i have a Table View Controller inside of a Navigation Controller inside of a Tab Bar Controller

(Tab Bar -> Navigation Controller -> Table View Controller)

When a Table View Cell selected show segue launches with a new Table View Controller.

What I want to achieve is to hide Tab Bar Controller and show Toolbar Controller inside the new view (Just like the behaviour in Whatsapp's Chats screen).

I am able to hide Tab Bar with hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=true in prepareForSegue but failed to show Toolbar. How can i achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with `setToolbarHidden` method in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
```